# Mule - Outbound Attachments lost in Http response

Tags: mule

I added an Attachment transformer to set an attachment and expected it will be delivered in the HTTP response. However I only see the payload string set in the flow.

```
<flow name="nonrestdownloadFlow1" doc:name="nonrestdownloadFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8083" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-attachment attachmentName="attachment.txt" value="dfsdkgnsgjkdfgjkdrng05305fgkgnkdfngkng04t04tkdgndjkgni" contentType="text/plain" doc:name="Add Attachment"/>
       <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="multipart/form-data" doc:name="Add content type"/>
        <set-payload doc:name="Set Payload" value="Hello, see attachment with this response"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

What am i missing? Can someone help me understand please

Thanks
Venkat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-5005

It's super old and so it seems it's never going to be fixed :(

You'll have to build the response you want yourself...

Comment: Thanks David that explains things. The [attachment transformer reference](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Attachment+Transformer+Reference) documentation still suggests HTTP is supported.